# How to restore default values in Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, mapscript

I'm using Mapscript reading a configuration of my map file, so i set some values in my mapObj. But in certain point of my code i need to restore the default values locate in map file. I tried to use the method "applyConfigOptions()", but didn't work. 
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can't you just reread the original MAP file again?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a mapscript developer and I'm afraid that's not possible with the stock mapscript.

You should implement the Memento pattern in your code as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) or you could use the clone() method to obtain a snapshot of the mapObj state to which you can eventually revert to.
Safest option is to implement Memento. clone() might not work of even crash your program.